# Simple reasoning for de Broglie relations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, waves, momentum

being fundamental in quantum theories de Broglie relation must be understood in a convenient way for which a three line reasoning is presented by Weinberg in "quantum theory of fields V.I P.3" but i don't understand line two and want clear explanation to it.

line one: if particles are described by a wave whose phase at position $x$ and time $t$ is of the form $2\pi({\bf k} x — \nu t)$, and if this phase is to be Lorentz invariant, then the vector ${\bf k}$ and the frequency $\nu$ must transform like $x$ and $t$, and hence like p and E.

(i understand (?) this because the presented phase is an inner product. now $(t,x,y,z)$ ${\it is}$ a 4-vector and if some 4-component thing have scalar result whenever product to such a thing it must be a 4-vector too, and so transform same as 4-vectors such as $(t,x,y,z)$ or $(E,p_1, p_2,p_3)$.)

line two: In order for this to be possible $\bf k$ and $\nu$ must have the same velocity dependence as $\bf p$ and $E$, and therefore must be proportional to them, with the same constant of proportionality.

(i don't understand!)

line three: For photons, one had the Einstein relation $E = h\nu$, so it was natural to assume that, for material particles, 
$$ {\bf k} = {\bf p}/h ,\quad v =E/h. $$

(which is clear)

Comment: I think that the point is that $(\nu, \vec{k})$ should be a four vector according to line 1: the first physically meaningful four-vector you can think is $(E, \vec{p})$. Hence you assume that $(\nu, \vec{k})$ is a multiple of $(E, \vec{p})$, the proportionality constant being $1/h$.